# Allow users to create sub users in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

Can anyone give some advice on how to create a custom module, which will allow users to create sub-users that are able to login through sugar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this functionality is already available  in sugar  to create sub user,But if you want to create your own Module then , just go through the existing module you will find a way.
Please go through this link to know more about Sub user creation.

[User management Sugarcrm 7.6](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/7.6/Ent/Administration_Guide/Users/)

[User management Sugarcrm 6.5](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/6.5/CE/Administration_Guide/Users/)

Thank you 
I guess It will help you.